Constructing a finite generating set $S'$ for a group $G$ which contains $N/\{1\}$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup.
Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, say by some $S$, and let $N$ be a nontrivial proper finite normal subgroup. I want to construct a finite generating set $S'$ such that set $N/\{1\}$ is contained in $S'$, $S\subseteq S'$, and for any $a,b\in S/N$ such that $a\neq b$, $a$ is not equivalent to $b$ modulo $N$.
Here's what I tried to do: I wrote $S=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_n\}$ and then I constructed a set $X=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_l\}$ for which each $s_j\in S$ is equivalent to exactly one element of $X$. Then I took the set $Y:=\bigcup_{x\in X}([x]\cap S)$ (where $[x]\in G/N$)  and then from here I defined $S':=Y\cup N/\{1\}$. It was easy to see that $S\subseteq S'$ and obviously $N/\{1\}$ is contained in $S'$. My issue is showing the last condition.
If $a,b\in S'/N$, $a\neq b$, and $a^{-1}b\in N$, then, writing $a=x_jn$ and $b=x_in'$ for $n,n'\in N$, I can conclude that $x_j=x_i$, from which follows that $a^{-1}b=n^{-1}n'$. But then where do I go from here?
For context, I'm trying to show that the quotient map $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ is a quasi-isometry without Svar-Milnor
Edit: I'm not sure if this qualifies as an answer to the question so I'll put it here. Such a generating set may not exist, but you don't need such a generating set to solve the problem. In particular, you can just take a set of representatives for the image of $S$ under the quotient map, say $X$, and set $S'=X\cup N/\{1\}$ (assume without loss of generality that $1\notin X$; if a generator is in $N$, just take a nontrivial element in $n$ to represent the equivalence class). It is then clear that $S\subseteq \langle X\cup N/\{1\}\rangle$, and so, it is a finite generating set for $G$ (since $N$ is finite). Now, $\pi(S'/N)=\pi(X\cup N/\{1\})$, which means that $\pi(S'/N)$ generates $G/N$. It is then easy to show that $\pi$ is a $(1,1)$-quasi-isometric embedding. Since it surjective, it has quasi-dense image. Thus, it is a quasi-isometry

Yiy should correct typos in the post. What you are asking for is unnecessary for a proof of quasi-isometry.

How should I go about it then?

Start by proving that the quotient map is Lipschitz. Then choose a right inverse to the quotient map any way you want and check that it is also coarse Lipschitz.

What does "coarse Lipschitz" mean?

What book are you reading? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982526/every-quasiisometry-is-a-quasiisometric-embedding

I'm basing most of my knowledge on Geometric Group Theory by Clara Loh. But there it is proved using Svarc-Milnor. The definition in that book is that one has a quasi-isometric embedding with a coarse inverse  which is also a quasi-isometric embedding. Any hints for how I should show that the right inverse is a coarse lipschitz?

The definition for quasi-isometry

Correct.........
